# For a module $M$ if $M=L_1\oplus L_2=M_1\oplus M_2 $ and $L_1=M_1$ then is $L_2=M_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

For a module $M$ if $M=L_1\oplus L_2=M_1\oplus M_2 $ and $L_1=M_1$ then is $L_2=M_2$?

What I know:

$L_1\cap L_2=0 ,~ L_1+L_2=M$

$M_1\cap M_2=0 ,~ M_1+M_2=M$

How can I prove the rest I couldnt do.

I will be appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the direct sum of the $x$-axis with *any* other $1$-dimensional subspace whatsoever. However, it will be true that $L_2 \cong M_2$ (can you see why?)

Comment: I guess I understood what you said. But this is just a counterexample. How can I prove that by use definitions or theorems. With that I can fully understand.

Comment: This counterexample *is* a proof. You asked if it is always true that $L_2 = M_2$, and the answer is no, which I proved by providing an example where $L_1 \oplus L_2 = M = M_1 \oplus M_2$ and $L_1 = M_1$, but $L_2 \neq M_2$. Does that help?

Comment: @BERAT How is it possible to prove something is true (that you already know to be false, as this example shows) by use of definitions and theorems? If you can use logic to see that $(L_1 \oplus L_2 = M_1 \oplus M_2 \ \ \& \ \ L_1 = M_1) \implies L_2 = M_2$, then something in your proof is wrong because that same logical steps does not work with this explicit example.